# Autoscaling in OpenStack Ocata

Tags: openstack, autoscaling, heat

Does someone have a simple autoscaling example (e.g. for two cirros instances and cpu/memory trigger) for OpenStack Ocata? I'm looking for a simple heat YAML file that can demonstrate.

Comment: Have you tried with `OS::Heat::AutoScalingGroup` resource? What is the issue you are facing while trying auto-scaling? Or is it that you don't know where to start?

Comment: Hi Kuro It creates the initial instances for the autoscaling group. I tried an old example using OS::Ceilometer::Alarm but the cpu_util just comes back with insufficient data.

Comment: Did you wait for more than 10 minutes? Please check your ceilometer/pipeline.yaml if `interval` is set to less than 600 or not? If not try setting it to 30 seconds and restart `ceilometer-polling` service

Comment: Yes I did and I've modified the intervals to 30. cpu_util doesn't show up in my meter list even after creating instances. My installation has three nodes running as VMs on top of XenServer - I wonder if that is my issue?